# If a problem has an infinite number of solutions, can there exist a complete algorithm for providing a solution of the problem?

Tags: logic

so my question is the following:

If a problem has an infinite number of solutions, can there exist a complete algorithm for providing a solution of the problem?

I use the term "complete" with respect to semantic validity.

To be more precise, let us assume that we have the following statement:

Given problem P, algorithm A terminates and returns $\sigma$, if and only if $\sigma$ a solution of P.

It might be the case that I can prove the "only if" part easily, because the algorithm has a way of determining one of the infinitely many solutions of P. (The algorithm is sound.)

However, if somebody comes up with a solution $\sigma$ of P, is it possible for an algorithm that will determine that particular solution $\sigma$ of P to exist? (That algorithm would be complete in my understanding.)

I think it should be an easy question, but it has been puzzling me..

edit://

For example, let us say that we have the following problem:

"Given an integer x, provide me with an integer y such that y > x."

So I make an algorithm that given x, returns x+1.

The algorithm is sound, as for any given integer x, integer x+1 will be greater than x and thus a solution to our problem.

However, the algorithm is not complete. Given x, one may come up with the integer x+2, which is again a solution to our problem,but one that my algorithm will never be able to provide for the given input x (it will always return x+1 and never x+2).

I wonder if for a given integer x, there could exist an algorithm that would be able to provide all of the solutions of our problem, thus rendering itself complete. It should not provide all of the solutions at once, but in every run it would provide a solution that could be any of the infinitely many solutions, thus, providing all of the infinitely many solutions of our problem in an infinite number of runs.

For example, given a particular integer x, the algorithm could return x+12 in the first run, x+2 in the second run, and so on, providing all the infinitely many solutions of our problem in an infinite number of runs.

It might be the case, that I am confused about the notion of completeness for this particular problem and its algorithm.

Comment: Which kind of problem are you interested ? Normally, it is easy to check, whether a given instance is a solution of a problem. The hard part usually is finding one.

Comment: I suppose it largely depends on what you mean by "providing" a complete solution.  Consider the "problem" of showing that there are infinitely many prime integers.  Most would consider this completely solved, in a variety of senses.  For example, in principle an algorithm can list all of the (positive) prime integers in increasing order.

Comment: Yes. Consider the problem of finding a rational approximation to the square root of $2$ that is accurate to within $.001$. There are an infinite number of solutions but we generally stop at the first one that works.

Comment: I gave a small example to clarify what I have in mind in a better way, hopefully..

Comment: Then your algorithm would have to be either non-deterministic or stateful. If you remember previous solutions then you can eliminate them from consideration in the future. Also note that the answer is a definite no for real computers because we are limited by precision.

Comment: @JohnDouma The way I understand it, an optimization algorithm that systematically uses different starting points is deterministic but need not be stateful.

Comment: The question as stated is very unclear. There are so many different problems with so many different types of solution sets that a "no" answer to your original question is impossible to come by. A "yes" answer ("*can* there be...") is easier: Systems of linear equations have either no solution, exactly one solution, or infinitely many. If there are infinitely many solutions, they form an affine space. A parametrization of the solution space describes infinitely many solutions in a finite amount of time and space.